# How to stream output of a shell command in a nodejs server using exec

Tags: linux, node.js, shell

I'm trying to write a simple webserver in nodejs that can execute arbitrary shell commands on a linux VM. the requirement for this service is that, the output should be printed both on the console on which the process is started using node in real time and also in browser. 
The current code which I have so far, doesn't output the stdout of a command till it finished completely.

How can I fix this, so I get live streaming output in the console as well as in the browser? Also, I want the status code of the request be non 200 for cmds that exit with non zero status code.

```
#!/usr/local/bin/node

var http = require('http'),
    url = require('url'),
    exec = require('child_process').exec;

var host = "127.0.0.1",
    port = "8080",
    thisServerUrl = "http://" + host + ":" + port;

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  req.addListener('end', function () {

  });
  var parsedUrl = url.parse(req.url, true);
  var cmd = parsedUrl.query['cmd'];

  console.log("CMD to run is " + cmd)
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});

  if( cmd ) {
    var child = exec(cmd, function (error, stdout, stderr) {
      var result = '{"stdout":' + stdout + ',"stderr":"' + stderr + '","cmd":"' + cmd + '"}';
      res.end(result + '\n');
    });
  } else {
    var result = '{"stdout":"' + '' + '","stderr":"' + 'cmd is mandatory' + '","cmd":"' + cmd + '"}';
    res.end(result + '\n');
  }
}).listen(port, host);
console.log('Server running at ' + thisServerUrl );
```

Comment: Use `spawn` instead of `exec`: http://www.hacksparrow.com/difference-between-spawn-and-exec-of-node-js-child_process.html

Comment: I don't think you'll be able to set a dynamic response status code if you stream your response body. Your child process has no status code until it exits at which point your stream closes. You'll need to choose between status code and response body streaming.